# Attempting to program ATmega88PB Atmel Studio error 0xc0

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel, avr-studio7

I am attempting to program an ATmega88PB using Atmel Studio 7 and both the AVRISP and Atmel ICE debugger. When attempting to read the device ID I get the following error message:

```
Failed to enter programming mode. ispEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)
```

This is on a custom board and I tried to resolder a new chip with no success. I have read that this issue may be due to a poor connector or the clock frequency being too high. I tried lowering the clock speed to 8kHz with no success.

When I pulled out the scope I found that the MOSI , sck, and reset pins do seem to be sending properly. However, I am not seeing any response from the MISO line (stays high).

Does anyone have any other ideas that I could attempt to debug this issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is having this issue... I am running off of a 3.3V setup but did not realize that in order to enter programming mode Vcc must be set to 4.5V - 5.5V. I isolated Vcc from the 3.3V line, applied 5V and it works great.

Comment: Not necessarily, read **33.8** of ATmega 88 PB manual. It clearly says that Vcc could be +1.8-5.5V. When programming with ATMELK ICE debugger ensure that you connect external power source right(Vtg to Vcc_ext and GND to external ground)

Comment: I don't see why why you would need 4.5V-5.5V either, except if you use a very high clock speed (>=20MHz).

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. You were right - there was something wrong with the seating of the MCU. I assembled another board and had no issues.